# OCISG file system creation error failed to authenticate

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am testing oracle cloud infrastructure storage gateway, when creating the first file system am facing the following error:

> The required information to complete authentication was not provided.

I tried to remove the public and private keys and recreate them, with no luck.

Could any one please advise for a solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions here ?

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/StorageGateway/Tasks/creatingyourfirstfilesystem.htm

Can you double check if you gave the following information correctly?

- User OCID
- Tenant OCID
- Compartment OCID

Can you please open a ticket with the support, if you are still facing the issue after following the above steps.